# Is it possible to use Boost.Format with a preallocated buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, boost-format

I was wondering whether [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/) does support using a fixed-width  / preallocated buffer as output instead of a dynamic buffer managed by the lib itself?

That is, normally you'd do:

```
boost::format myfmt("arg1: %1% / arg2: %2%");
// e.g.:
cout << (myfmt % 3.14 % 42);
// or
string s = boost::str( myfmt % "hey!" % "there!");
```

so the Boost:Format lib will automatically take care of allocating enough space and managing the "output buffer" for you.

I was wondering if there's any way to use a predefine non-dynamic buffer with Boost.Format, that is, something like:

```
const size_t buf_sz = 512;
char big_enough[buf_sz];
boost::format myfmt("arg1: %1% / arg2: %2%");
myfmt.attach_buffer(big_enough, buf_sz);
myfmt % "hey!" % "there!"
// big_enough buffer now contains the result string
```

I know I could just sift through the examples, the docs and the source, but apart from lacking time atm. (and the very possibility of missing something) it would be interesting to know: 
*If it is not possible, it would be great if someone could explain why* (if there is/are specific whys) -- was it deliberate? doesn't it match the API well? ...?

**Disclaimer:**  This question is **not** about performance!

Comment: What do you want to happen when you run out of room?   For a fixed buff I would use snprintf, but that's me :)

Comment: @nhed If it doesn't fit, the library can/could either throw an exception or just stop filling the buffer (similar to [the options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#exceptions) already available)

Comment: I'm not sure that those exceptions apply to the target buffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Initial Idea

Looking at the [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/format/format_class.hpp) it seems you can use your own allocator which is then used by the internal stream (`internal_streambuf_t`) of `boost::format`. Would that be good enough for your case?

For example you could use something like the libstdc++ [array_allocator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00031.html)

Unfortunately `boost::format` also uses a couple of `std::vector` which do not use the custom allocator which may be a problem in your case?

## How `boost::format` works

I looked into the source of `boost::format` and this is how it works (described below is `str()`, `<<` calls either `str()` or uses standard `std::ostream` stuff) :

- the format class stores all arguments and format string separatly, sometimes using the custom allocator, sometimes using the default allocator
- when `str()` is called it creates a new `std::string` and makes it large enough for the result using the custom allocator
- it then appends all arguments and static string pieces from the format string to the result string
- finally it returns the result string by value

So, the final result string is not stored inside the format class but created when needed.

So even if you can find the location of the result string when using a custom allocator, it is only available after/during a call to `str()`.
This should explain why it is not possible: the formatted result is never stored inside an "output buffer" in the class.

## Why it works like this

Why they did it this way I do not know. I think it is because you can only build the result after all arguments are known, it wastes space to store the result and you probably only need the result just once for a given format/argument combination. So creating it when needed does not result in extra work since typically `str()` is only called once.

## Solutions

- Create some wrapper around `str()` or `<<` and copy the result into your fixed buffer
- Use a `stream_buffer` to 'stream' the string into the buffer (see example below)
- Inherit the class and add your own `str()` function which stores the result in a fixed buffer.

Possible solution using [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/guide.html) (tested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];

    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_sink>
        stream(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    stream << (boost::format("arg1 = %1%") % 12.5);
    stream << '\0';  // make sure buffer contains 0-terminated string

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;    
}
```

Comment: Useful info. I think a slight problem with allocators is that they are only allowed to report failure via bad_alloc, correct?

Comment: @Martin: I think you are right. Also, I looked into the source of format and I think using an allocator is difficult to do. I have updated my answer with the things I found.

Comment: Nice job! Do I understand you correctly: The output string is re-built every time `.str()` is called?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, the output string is re-build every time `str()` is called.